# Simulating Pareto distribution in R Jags (Bayesian)

Tags: r, bayesian, jags

I'm trying to simulating the Pareto distribution in R jags to get the posterior mean and 95% credible set for α.

The Pareto distribution for y ≥ u is:

f(y;α,u)= αu^α / y^(α+1), u,α > 0, and f(y;α,u) = 0 when y < u

The expectation is E[Y;α,u] = αu/(α − 1) if α > 1 and ∞,otherwise.

I'm using dpar(alpha, u) to compute the distribution for y ≥ u in JAGS.

Set u = 35 and under the uniform prior, p(α) = U[0, 50], generate 20,000 posterior samples with thin=1 and n.adapt=1000. This is the code I did, but I'm not too sure about the likelihood and 
the model. 
Any help would be appreciate!

```
cat("model
{   
    alpha ~ dpar(50,35)
  #Not too sure about the code above
  }", file="HIghTemp.csv")
data_temp = list(temp$MaxTemp)
jags.temp = jags.model(file="HIghTemp.csv",data=data_temp,n.chains=1, n.adapt=1000)
params.temp=c("alpha")
samps.temp = coda.samples(jags.temp, params.temp, n.iter=20000,thin=1)
summary(samps.temp)
```